# How to make spotlight search more effective at locating commonly used directories?

Tags: spotlight, search

Spotlight Search - <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> - doesn't seem to find the Applications folder, despite it being on of the most well-known and important folders on the macOS:

[image]

Same happens in a quick search for the Documents folder (bizarrely, it even brings up *google searches* for the term 'documents folder'):

[image]

Is there a way to make Spotlight Search prioritise commonly used macOS
folders/programs/settings for quick access?

Comment: Do you have Folders selected as a search type in prefs? https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0TZ4.png

Comment: @Tetsujin great thinking. Funnily enough, I do have Folders selected: https://imgur.com/a/1Tmmkem (but we seem to get *very* different spotlight search results!)

Comment: I can confirm that spotlight shows folders, including documents and applications. Interesting note: My system language is in german, but I can search "keychain access" in spotlight and it displays the "Schlüsselbundverwaltung". However, I can't search for "Applications", I have to search for "Programme" in spotlight to show the correct folder.

Comment: Simple question - why? To have two steps (find folder, find file/app within folder) instead of one (find file/app)? My experience is that macOS does learn and prioritize based on my usage of Spotlight.  Also keep in mind that intended usage of Spotlight according to [Apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/spotlight-mchlp1008/mac) is: "Spotlight can help you quickly find apps, documents, and other files on your Mac.". Note absence of folders.